# how to display the last updated record in 2 tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created 2 tables(businesstbl, businessupdatestbl). Now, I want to display the LAST RECORD for each business has added. The table should look like this:

businesstbl

```
 bus_id   bus_name    
  1         bus1       
  2         bus2
```

businessupdatestbl

```
  bus_up_id   bus_up_description   bus_id(FK)   bus_up_date
   1            description1        1             2013-12-02
   2            description2        1             2013-01-02
   3            description3        2             2013-01-29  
   4            description4        2             2013-02-01
   5            description4        2             2013-01-01
```

**The result should be:**

```
  bus_id   bus_name   bus_up_description
   1        bus1       description1    
   2        bus2       description4
```

Comment: Please show what you tried, what you got, and what you'd like to have gotten.

Answer (score 1):

```
select b.*, bu.*
from businesstbl b
join businessupdatestbl bu on b.bus_id = bu.bus_id
join 
(
   select bus_id, max(bus_up_date) as max_bus_up_date
   from businessupdatestbl
   group by bus_id
) bumax on on bu.bus_id = bumax.bus_id and bu.bus_up_date = bumax.max_bus_up_date
```

Comment: thank you but I have a syntax error  "Every derived table must have its own alias"

Comment: I got it.. you just mistakenly typed in "on" twice.. thanks much